# then next button doesnt work on new activity windown

Tags: android, android-studio

when I start a new project then window comes create the new project then I enter app name domain and location and hit next button. In next window, it takes me to target Android devices. I don't change anything and hit next and after that new window appears and titled (Add an activity to mobile ) I choose an empty activity. Then I hit next button and after that window appears Customize the activity I leave it to default values and hit next button but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: click finish man.

Comment: Don't forget to breathe :P :P

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to press the next as it's at the end so the **Finish** button is the one you should press.